# SQL Update Table confusion?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables, `communication`(that has a column `timestamp`,`FromIDNumber` and `FromX` ) and `commLocation`(that has a column `timestamp`,`FromIDNumber` and `x`).

I want to set `communication.FromX = commLocation.x` when the two tables have the same `timestamp` and `FromIDNumber`.

I tried doing this:

```
UPDATE communication
SET FromX=(SELECT commLocation.x
           FROM commLocation 
           JOIN communication
           ON communication.Timestamp=commLocation.timestamp
           WHERE communication.FromIDNumber=commLocation.FromIDNumber);
```

But I got an error:

```
You can't specify target table 'communication' for update in FROM clause
```

How would I accomplish this? This is the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92999/1)** for it. Right now, I'm inserting the `FromX` values at the end of the table, and I don't want that because I need it to correspond to a certain row of `communication`.... how would I do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a JOIN operation in an UPDATE statement.

For example:

```
  UPDATE communication c
    JOIN commLocation l
      ON l.timestamp    = c.timestamp
     AND l.fromidnumber = c.fromidnumber
     SET c.fromx = l.x
```

This assumes that `(timestamp,fromidnumber)` is unique in `commLocation`.

---

For developing a query like this, we usually start with a SELECT statement...

```
  SELECT c.timestamp 
       , c.fromidnumber
       , c.fromx        AS old_fromx
       , l.x            AS new_fromx
    FROM communication c
    JOIN commLocation l
      ON l.timestamp    = c.timestamp
     AND l.fromidnumber = c.fromidnumber
```

The `new_fromx` in the SELECT is the expression/value we're going to assign to the column. We can return additional columns in the SELECT list, to verify the statement is doing what we want it to do.

Once we get that working, we convert that into an update by removing the `SELECT ... FROM` and replacing it with `UPDATE`.  And adding a `SET` clause before the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, I'll keep it in mind next time I'm writing an `UPDATE` query!

Comment: It might just be me that does that, writing a SELECT statement first. I'm not smart enough to get the UPDATE statement with a join correct the first time around.  But I can mess around with a SELECT statement, (adding/removing predicates, checking for null values, do I want an outer join? am I matching too many rows?, etc) without screwing up any data. Once I'm certain I've got it right, then I convert it into an UPDATE. (But I might be the only one that does that.)